# Autocomplete by the first letter on PURE JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there some way to make autocompleting by the first letter for select dropdown list not on jQuery but on PURE JavaScript? Something like [only example !!!]:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="autoComplete();" />
<select id="mySelectDropdwonList">
  <option>John</option>
  <option>Michael</option>
  <option>Toml</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function autoComplete() {
  // what is the code ??
}
</script>
```

It should work like the jQuery-solution by the link http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ but on pure JS

Comment: What is wrong with the question?

Comment: You have put 0 effort into trying to come up with a solution yourself and have not described what you expect to happen.  Perhaps google how auto-complete works first before begging someone to do it for you.

Comment: question is sadly lacking in enough detail to even know what it is supposed to do. A mousedown on a select won't do anything for you

Comment: So basically you want a combobox in Javascript instead of jQuery?

Comment: Start by inspecting the live html that the plugin creates. If that's what you want to do...follow their example and add event handlers after

Comment: use the _list_ attrib on a text input

Answer (score 6):

A solution just in HTML5:

```html
<input type="text" list="mySelectDropdwonList" />
<datalist id="mySelectDropdwonList">
    <option>John</option>
    <option>Michael</option>
    <option>Toml</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're the only one who really read the question

Comment: maybe an other answer of me is enlighten you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154877/use-html5-datalist-autocomplete-with-contains-approach-not-just-starts-wit/32394157#32394157