# Search/filter for an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a search function for an array. I have a input[text] where for example I put 'ban', then I need all results that start with 'ban' to show up, for example banana, banana milkshake, banana(fried), etc.

How would I go about doing this? I tried, but every time I try it isn't accurate. What I tried is below.

What I have:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('ingredient');
var ingredienten = ["Appel", "Aardbei", "Aardappelen", "Banaan", "Bananen", "Banana"]

inputBox.onkeydown = function(evt) {
      $("#autocomplete").empty();

      // INSERT CODE FOR SEARCH FUNCTION


}
```

I had one that came very close, however when I typed 'ban' it came up with 'Aardbei'. Which is obviously wrong. Here it is, maybe I overlooked something?

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('ingredient');
var ingredienten = ["banaan", "bananen", "baan", "banana", "baaanana"];

inputBox.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    $("#autocomplete").empty();

    var input, filter, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = inputBox.value.toUpperCase();
    for (i = 0; i < ingredienten.length; i++) {
        a = ingredienten[i];
        if (a.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        //console.log(a);
        $("#autocomplete").append("<li>" + a + "</li>");
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to do an autocompletion ?

Comment: First of all use onkeyup event instead of onkeydown.

Comment: maybe this helps, too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29154877/1447675

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use the `keyup` event instead and you can make use of a regex and the `filter` function on the array of items:

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('ingredient');
var ingredienten = ["Appel", "Aardbei", "Aardappelen", "Banaan", "Bananen", "Banana"]

inputBox.onkeyup = function(evt) {
    $("#autocomplete").empty();

    var query = $('#ingredient').val();

    // escape regex
    query = query.replace(
      /[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"
    );
    var queryRegExp = new RegExp('^' + query, 'i');
    
    var results = ingredienten.filter(function(item) {
        return queryRegExp.test(item);
    });
   
    results.forEach(function(item) {
        $("#autocomplete").append("<li>" + item + "</li>");
    });
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="ingredient" />
<div id="autocomplete"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Using [jQuery UI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) this task can be done very easily:

```js
$('#ingredient').autocomplete({
    source: ["Appel", "Aardbei", "Aardappelen", "Banaan", "Bananen", "Banana"]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<input id="ingredient">
```

Answer (score 1):

Going under the instructions, you can use a regular expression filter here on your array.

```
const results = ingredienten.filter(item => item.match(/^ban/)); //add i at the end to ignore case
```

This will iterate the array and return all the results that match the regex "starts with 'ban'".

You can also do a 0-2 substring match == 'ban' but that's a bit more manual.